# Using Shift+Tab keys causes selection issue in Kendo DropDownList jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

Using Shift+Tab keys causes selection issue in DropDownList:

Could you help me to define the related issue for using Shift+Tab keys with DropDownLists to go back to the previous control?

I handled specific functionality for Enter key to focus and open dropdownlist automatically. Then after user selects an item from dropdownlist and presses Enter key, the handled functionality moves the focus to the next dropdownlist and opens it automatically and all of this works as expected.

However, on the other hand when I tried to handle the functionality of using Shift+Tab to go back to the previous dropdownlist and open it automatically and then select specific item by using Enter key .. the drop down list selection is not working successfully and dropdownlist stays opened.

Comment: Please post code sample / snippet